# Is back flow from UPS inverter normal?

Tags: power-supply, ups

I have a pure sine wave UPS / inverter for the combi boiler, and noticed a weird thing. That kind of UPS that has a big heavy transformer inside that is connected to a big car / truck battery. If I unplug every consumer from the UPS, and I unplug the UPS itself, when I measure from one of the pins of the UPS plug.to the earth / grounding of the power socket, I get 98 volts AC.

Is this normal? From the first view, the UP seems to be faulty, and this can represent a big risk.

Some notes:

- I live in a country with 230V/50Hz
  -Earthing system: TN-C-S system
- UPS: VOLT Polska Sinus PRO 800 VA

Comment: Have you tried measuring the DC voltage in the same place?

Comment: We can't know if this is normal, or not, because there is no info how it works internally, how it is installed, and how it is supposed to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your AC measurement is also capable of measuring a DC level (many meters will do this) and, it's likely that you are measuring the stored DC voltage on EMI filtering capacitors.

> *Is this normal?*

It's not "normal" but I've certainly seen it on some appliances. I had an old vacuum cleaner that when the plug was removed from the wall, if you touched the L and N prongs on the plug you would get a mild-to-painful shock.

> *From the first view, the UP seems to be faulty, and this can represent
> a big risk.*

If my assumption is correct then, it's probably not faulty.